# trying to book train tickets in india witout an indian phone number

Tags: india

I had an IRCTC account for years, wasnt too active. I am returning to india on a visit and trying to book tickets ahead. Changed my number on IRCTC to a foreign one, paid the 100 INR fee, but the account seems to be stuck in limbo. WHen I login it keeps saying that I need further verification but never goes on
what should I do?